# How to print the string preceding a specific word in shell?

Tags: string, bash, shell

I have a string and I want to print all the substrings that end with a specific word in shell, example

```
This is a echo test example echo please help me echo with this echo question
```

I want its output to be

```
This is a echo
This is a echo test example echo
This is a echo test example echo please help me echo
This is a echo test example echo please help me echo with this echo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed :

```
$ sed -n 's/ echo/&\n/g;:a;/echo\n/P;s/echo\n/echo/;ta' file
This is a echo
This is a echo test example echo
This is a echo test example echo please help me echo
This is a echo test example echo please help me echo with this echo
```

Comment: That was just an example. Actually I wouldn't be knowing how many times the word occur.

Comment: @AmitManchanda This sed does not operate on the number of occurrences. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -vword="echo" '{var="";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){var=var$i""FS;if(index($i,word) > 0){print var"\n"}}}' < file
```

via awk script file

```
awk -vword="echo" -f script.awk  < file
```

**script.awk**

```
#! /bin/awk -f
{
    var="";
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        var=var$i""FS;
        if(index($i,word) > 0){
            print var"\n"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Observing the following:

```
$ input='This is a echo test example echo please help me echo with this echo question'
$ grep -Po '.*?echo' <<< "$input"
This is a echo
 test example echo
 please help me echo
 with this echo
```

With a non-greedy regex match, we get a sequence of lines all ending with `echo`.

We use this command as the input to a shell loop, in which we reassemble the original sentence and print the current status after each line:

```
str=
while IFS= read -r line; do
    str+="$line"
    echo "$str"
done < <(grep -Po '.*?echo' <<< "$input")
```

resulting in

```
This is a echo
This is a echo test example echo
This is a echo test example echo please help me echo
This is a echo test example echo please help me echo with this echo
```